# sql count of rows from two tables where rows from table 1 don't exist in table 2

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables in a SQLite db like so

```
|  t1           |
|===============|
| t1_id | other |
|-------|-------|
| 1     | sdfds |
| 2     | asdaa |
| 3     | lkjeq |


|  t2                   |
|=======================|
| t2_id | t1_id | other |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 1     | 1     | dggeh |
| 2     | 1     | iohio |
| 3     | 3     | ytucc |
| 4     | 3     | .noih |
| 5     | 3     | /oioi |
```

There are approx. 300K+ rows in both tables. I want the counts of **t1** that have related rows in **t2** as well as those that don't have. That is,

```
"count of t1 with related t2"   : 2
"count of t1 with no related t2": 1
```

Of course, I can get "count of t1 with related t2" from

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id;
```

and the "count of t1 with no related t2" by subtracting the above from the total count of **t1**. But how can I get it from a SQL query efficiently? I tried the following

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT t1_id FROM t1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t.t1_id = t2.t1_id);
```

and I see that the index on `t1_id` in table **t2** is not used. When I try the query, it takes really long, like 100s of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM
 (SELECT t1_id FROM t1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT t1_id FROM t2);
```

or

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM t1
WHERE t1_id NOT IN (SELECT t1_id FROM t2);
```

or (A slight variation on your original):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.t1_id = t2.t1_id);
```

All three of those should use an index on `t2(t1_idx)`. You'll have to do benchmarking on real data to see which is faster.